# Python Logging: Exception clears log file

Tags: python-3.x, logging

Looking for a hint of what to look for:
I inherited some code and am going through the process of reviewing/debugging.  The author put lots of `logging.info` calls throughout the code which looked promising.  The `main.py` has the following:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='struc2vec.log', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
```

When I monitor the file size of the log file while the program runs, the file size increases and decreases eg. 5k..6k...2k...6k...  If I randomly stop the program I can see that some things have been written to the file BUT if there is an exception that crashes the program the log file is cleared.

It is as if the logging is being reinitialized over and over.  The docs for logging indicate the file size should just keep increasing (DEBUG mode) indefinitely.  There are a number of modules and each one imports `logging`, does that make a difference?  What should I look for that might be clearing or overwriting the log file repeatedly?

Comment: When the program starts over the log is cleared, or are you saying that the log file is cleared if the program crashes?

Comment: The program may have a `RotatingFileHandler` somewhere other than the `main` function, that keeps reinitializing when it surpasses a certain file size. Pretty overkill if the program's only rotating a single file though.

Comment: @JonSG if there is a crash, the log file is cleared.

Comment: @no_hex I cannot find a file handler anywhere.  There is just the `logging.basicConfig()` declaration and then a lot of `logging.info()` calls.  There is nothing else that writes to the log file.

Comment: Solved(?)  the `filemode='w'` is the problem.  It truncates the file before writing.  If I us the option 'a', logging is appended and the file grows as expected.  The exception happens in a method writing data to disk I'm guessing the truncation takes place but the failure happened before the log could be written.  My guess.